# How can bind the "areaName" on <TexBox> vlaue=" " and onChange=" ":?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, api, arraylist

Actually, I have called an API and map the array and bind the data on `<TableCell>`

```
 {this.state.allArea.map((allArea, i) => (
                    <TableRow >
                        <TableCell >{allArea.areaName}</TableCell>
                <TableCell  >{allArea.cityName}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell > <IconButton aria-label="edit" onClick= 
                  {this.addCoupon.bind(this)}  >
                                   <EditIcon />
                     </IconButton><IconButton aria-label="delete">
                        <DeleteIcon />
                       </IconButton></TableCell> </TableRow>
                 ))}
```

But Now, I want  to edit/update the `areaName` so I create a `<TexBox>`

```
       <Grid container spacing={8}>
                <Grid item md={12} sm={12} xs={12} >
                    <TextBox error='' value='' name="name" label="Area name" required={true} onChange={this.handleAreaChange.bind(this)} ></TextBox>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
```

but I am unable to bind areaName at `value=""` and `onChange=''`

Answer (score 0):

Define like this

```
  <TextBox error='' value={areaName} 
   name="name" label="Area name" 
   required={true} onChange={this.handleAreaChange} >
  </TextBox>
```

`handleAreaChange` function

```
  handleAreaChange=e=>{
   this.setState({areaName:e.target.value})
  }
```

Comment: I have already try it but  it's showing `areaName` is not defined because of the <TableCell >{allArea.areaName}</TableCell>  scope is limitted till <TableBody>

Comment: @VijayGehlot share your allArea array

Comment: this.state={
          allArea:[ ]

      } ```http.post('allAreaOfCity')
            .then(res => {
                console.log('All-Area',res.data.area);
                this.setState({ allArea: res.data.area, isLoading: false })
            })```

Comment: @VijayGehlot can you share your code in sandbox?... and i asked for json response.